# T is a type, which is not valid in the given context when adding it to dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I need the idea of the class to be stored in the Dictonary, which is inherited by the interface, but I have a problem with not understanding how to add it to the Dictionary, here is the code.

```
ReportGenerator: IReportGenerator

res.Add<ReportGenerator>(ReportType.GenericReport);

private Dictionary<ReportType, IReportGenerator> Reports;

public void Add<T>(ReportType type)
    where T : IReportGenerator
{
    Reports.Add(type, T);
}
```

I get the error

> T is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: What value would you expect to be adding to the dictionary? All you've got is a type at the moment. Perhaps you want to create an *instance* of `T`? If so, you'd need to add the `new()` constraint for `T` as well.

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to put the tim itself in the Dictionary, not an instance

Comment: you probably wanted `void Add<T>(ReportType type, T element)...` and `Reports.Add(type, element);`?

Comment: You want to add the `Type` of `T`? If so, use `Reports.Add(type, typeof(T));`

Comment: @RenéVogt I need to put a type there, not an instance

Comment: But that's not possible, your dictionary expects an instance of `IReportGenerator`, not a type.

Comment: But the problem is that I need to have an IReportGenerator in the Dictionary so that in the future I can get it from there and call the necessary method

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to store a `Type` of `IReportGenerator` in the dictionary so it should be declared as

```
private Dictionary<ReportType, Type> Reports;
```

and then:

```
public void Add<T>(ReportType type)
    where T : IReportGenerator
{
    Reports.Add(type, typeof(T));
}
```

You're still constraining `where T : IReportGenerator` so if you're using this dictionary later to create instances of the types (and assuming you're only using this `Add` method to add to the dictionary!), you can be sure they will all be of type `IReportGenerator`.

There are *many* ways to create instances from types, but one simple way would be

```
var reportType = Reports[ReportType.GenericReport];
var report = (IReportGenerator)Activator.CreateInstance(reportType);
```

---

If you actually want *instances* of your report generator in the dictionary go back to the original:

```
private Dictionary<ReportType, IReportGenerator> Reports;
```

But give your `Add` method another constraint `new` and create an instance and put it in the dictionary:

```
public void Add<T>(ReportType type)
    where T : IReportGenerator, new()
{
    Reports.Add(type, new T());
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that I need to have an IReportGenerator in the Dictionary so that in the future I can get it from there and call the necessary method

Comment: @JonnyJon44 then make up your mind! Do you want instances, or do you want types? Your comment on the q (_"I need to put a type there, not an instance"_) said you wanted types. Note you can create instances from types!

Comment: In Dictionary I already need an instance, but in Add I can only pass the type

Comment: @JonnyJon44 See updates to answer, hopefully one of them solves your problem